# Hash and compare changes in specific webpage in Android application

Tags: android, web, hash

I´m working on a simple application which will create a notification if the content of specific website has been changed. Can anyone explain me how to do so? Thanks

P.S. Already took a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Here´s what I need to do exactly. I have Android app with few fragments in it, where one of them will show when the website content has been changed. And the problem is I don´t know how to do this: create java class which will hash the webpage (like kernel.org) every tho hours, compare it and if the first hash doesn´t match the new one, create notification.

Comment: you have seen this **"Search, and research"** in above link?

Comment: Yes, already did. But I don´t know how to do the thing I want to do. At least the people here are not downvoting as soon as they see noob here, yet.

Comment: [SO] is really about answering specific programming questions, take a look at [help/on-topic] for a more detailed explanation. You're asking a broad, open-ended question with many possible answers and that's not really what the site is for. You're going to have to specify and narrow it down more. You may need to figure out exactly what have in mind first.

Comment: Any decent book on Android app development will cover how to make HTTP requests, how to do periodic work, and how to raise notifications. What book did you read, and did it not cover these topics? The only thing about your problem that I would not expect Android books to cover would be the hashing part, and a Google search on `java generate hash` turns up quite a bit of material.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, i'll také a look at that